# WAMPSERVER Server not working

Tags: windows, apache, wamp, wampserver

I have just installed wampserver on windows 7 it works fine for me but when i restart windows and click on Start Wamp Server it starts but not showing any page at http://localhost i have not any skype or any service install let me know how can i fix that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is your user account one that has Administrator privileges? Did you try to start the Wamp Server using the 'Run as Administrator' option?

Comment: of course it has Administrator Privliges and how can i check if any other service is on port 80

Comment: @testkhan 1) Open command prompt. 2) Type 'netstat -o -n -a | findstr 0.0:80'. 3) The last column of every returned entry is a Process ID. 4) Open up the Task Manager, and find the process with the matching ID from the previous step. That should do it.

Comment: i have do that as u mentions it shows me an id which is associated to wampapache but it still not working

Answer (score 0):

Stop Wamp Server again. Does it change the behaviour?

If not, there must be any other service running on port 80.